# cutycapt SSL handshake failed, --insecure has no effect

Tags: image, ssl, web

Problem: Using cutycapt --insecure option has no effect for SSL handshake, images still produce "SSL handshake failed"

Command used:

```
cutycapt --url=https://10.11.1.8 --out=test2.png --insecure
```

Trouble shooting:

- Tried placing the flag around the command in different spots.
- Check I am running cutycat from 2013, there is no way I can see to look up the version.

Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Does `https://10.11.1.8` even work in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I am warned by the Firefox browser that the self signed cert is not trusted. I accept the risk and then I am brought to brought to an error page for Burp Suite Community Edition.

Comment: *" .... and then I am brought to brought to an error page for Burp Suite Community Edition"* - this suggests to me that you are not connecting to 10.11.1.8 with Firefox but that you have configured Burp as a proxy. In this case you are not testing if Firefox can access the site but if Firefox can access the Burp proxy (it can) and if Burp can access the site - which looks like it cannot either. This suggests that the site itself is configured wrong, i.e. the problem is not with cutycapt or Burp but with the target - which we know nothing about and thus cannot says what's wrong there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. 
I turned off my proxy / burp suite, also disabled the plugin to firefox for the proxy. 
Now I can get to the site via https on 443. Therefore the site is active on this port and using https. Performed the same command above, and same handshake failure from cutycapt. --insecure does not work.

What is odd is it works for some sites, but not others. I dont understand why.

Comment: *"What is odd is it works for some sites, but not others."* - this sounds like a cipher or TLS protocol problem then. For example browsers still support ciphers like 3DES in order·to connect to some older sites. Current builds of OpenSSL and other TLS libraries instead don't support this weak cipher. More information could be provided if one would know which sites work and which not.